# Should I be wary of sellers offering '14k gems' at heavily discounted prices?

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-royale

In telegram, there are many sellers that selling 14k gems + gift for around $25.

Is there any tricks or glitches behind it?

Should I avoid these sellers?

Comment: If it seems too good to be true, it probably is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a gaming-related matter.

Answer (score 4):

The only legitimate way to get gems in either Clash game is through the games themselves. Stated another way, anyone who tries to sell gems to you outside of the game is scamming you. If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is **UNLESS** it is a super value offer *inside* the game.

If for some reason you manage to obtain unauthorized gems, especially a large amount like 14000, without going through the payment process, Supercell may detect this and you can be banned, regardless of your real-money purchases, which are not refunded.

Source: Personal experience - gem hacks tested, does not work; got scammed out of $8 of Bitcoin once.

Comment: $8 of bitcoins back in 2009 or $8 of bitcoins now?

Comment: Although it's not relevant, $8 of bitcoins 6 months ago

Answer (score 0):

To ask that question is to answer it. You do not know the person enough yet to actually consider giving money. I always say "Do I know him as well as I know my Neighbors cat that gets in my lawn." Because I always know that the Cat will be offering a belly rub and I give it. Then I pet him and I leave. Win Win, not Lose Lose.